# Understanding eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to follow the discussion on eigenvectors and eigenvectors in the QM book by Cohen-Tannoudji, et. al.

If $\mathscr{A}$ is a $N \times N$ matrix with $A_{ij}$ as its entry at $i$th row and $j$th column, $c_j$ the $j$th component of the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $$\sum_j [A_{ij} - \lambda \delta_{ij}]c_j = 0\tag{1}\label{1}.$$ The above equation can be considered to be a system of $N$ linear and homonegeneous equations. I understand till here. What I don't understand is the following.

Consider $\lambda_0$ to be a simple eigenvalue of the characteristic equation $\operatorname{Det}[\mathscr A - \lambda I] = 0$. Now the authors say that \ref{1} is comprised of $N-1$ linear equations, the $N$th one following from the preceeding ones and hence redudant. How did we get $N-1$ linear equations?

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda_0$ is a simple eigenvalue, which means that its algebraic multiplicity is equal to its geometric multiplicity which is equal to one.
Let $\mathcal M$ be the representative matrix of the linear map $f$, with $\mathcal M \in \operatorname{M}(N\times N,\mathbb K)$.

You know that an eigenvector $\underline v$ associated to an eigenvalue $\bar \lambda$ belongs to $Ker(\mathcal f-\bar \lambda id)$, and the geometric multiplicity gives us also its dimension $\implies \underline v\in Sol\Big(\big(\mathcal M-\bar \lambda I_N)\underline x|$ $\underline 0\big)\Big)$.
So, in your case, $1=dim(Ker(f-\bar \lambda id))=N-\text rk(\mathcal M-\lambda_0 I_N)$ which means that $\text rk(\mathcal M-\lambda_0 I_N)$ is equal to $N-1$ that is also the number of linearly independent equations of the system $\big(\big(\mathcal M-\lambda_0I_N\big)\underline x|\underline 0\big)$.